# Why does my regex has a strange behavior? Is this a bug?

Tags: python, regex

I have some problems with my regex. I would like to retrieve the string before a comment. This string can be surrounded by quotation marks or not.

If I put a # (a comment) in quotes, I want it to be a string and not a comment.

Here is my regular expression:

```
[\"']?(.*?)[\"']?\s*(#.*)
```

Here are some functional examples with this regex:

```
"test" # comment    ---> group1: test   group2: # comment
test # comment      ---> group1: test   group2: # comment
```

Here's what I'm having trouble with and I do not understand:

```
"t#est" # comment   ---> group1: t      group2: #est" # comment
```

I want `group1: t#est` `group2: # comment`

[My regex with Regex1O1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDfmZ.png)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It would be better to link to your real regex101 rather than to an image of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should capture the initial quote (if any) and then use a backreference later to ensure that if the first `'"` was matched, `'"` is required at the end of the match before the `#`:

```
([\"']?)(.*?)\1\s*(#.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Rpb5wL/1

(note that since the initial quote is now captured, you'll have to change the code that uses the resulting groups to account for that - eg, the `#` part will now be in the 3rd group, not the 2nd group)

Comment: Wow, thank you for your very quick answer!Is there a way to not capture the first quote?

Comment: You could also alternate between the different possibilities, but capture + backreference looks nicer IMO

Answer (score 1):

You made the opening/closing quotes optional, but aren't consistent. They should either both be there or neither should be. And they should match, `"a'` is not a proper string.

A string surrounded by quotes is `\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'`. A string without quotes preceding a comment is `[^#]*`.

This makes our total regex:

```
(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^#]*)\s*#(.*)
```